# Can we store maize along with husk and kernal?

Tags: agriculture, plant

I'm a maize farmer and I'm almost ready for harvest.

I'm planning to store my harvest for some time.

Below are my questions:

1. How long can I store my harvest?
2. Can I sun dry my harvest with husk and kernel intact?
3. Can I store this sun-dried harvest with husk and kernel intact?

Comment: this question is a poor fit for this site but you can try to ask over at https://gardening.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Well, it depends on, what do we understand on "Earth" :-) There is no agriculture SE yet... there should be one...

Comment: Btw, we have an "agriculture" tag with 47 questions.

Comment: here is some information about the storage of maize http://www.fao.org/3/x0530e/X0530E05.htm

Answer (score 3):

For the (1) you can store your whole maize for 8 - 12 years or 18 - 36 months if the maize is ground or chopped. Moreover the less moisture the maize has the more it can be stored. If you want to store your harvest for a long period of time then the maximum moisture  percentage is 13.5%.

Comment: Hi geokord, can you give some background towards your answer?  Are there text sources that you got some of this information from, or is it your experience in doing such practices (and if so, how much experience)? That way people can better gauge how reliable the answer is. :-)

Comment: The background of my post was from a course I attended in my university. So I think it is a reliable answer.

Comment: ok, fair enough :-)  For the future, it's usually best to include that in the answer. The best answer is always one with reference support (the amount of time I've spent digging through old books/websites trying to find long-since-unused things :-( )... lacking that, definite next-best is well-explained reasoning to the answer... but when you at least have some context that adds a little credence, like yours, it's still probably useful towards getting to the answer. So long as the site isn't just people coming along saying "well I think this" or "it's this" (just because I think so) :-D

Comment: Now if only we could get a true Ag SE.  One of many pulled for back in the day on Area51 before the rules got so negative towards new site creation :-(

Comment: @geokord Any idea if kernel can be stored along with husk?